# how to add `required` attribute to angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes

I defined simple directive as you can see below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('biSelect', biSelect);

    function biSelect($compile) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'bi-select.html',
            scope: {
                required: '=?required'
            },
            controller: BiSelectController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        };

        return directive;
    }

    function BiSelectController() {
        var vm = this;
    }
})();
```

and this is directive template:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

now i want to add `required` attribute to `select` in directive when it was passed to directive, for example:

```
<bi-select required></bi-select>
```

how can i do that?

Comment: You should worry about how to add the `ng-model` attribute before worrying about the `required` attribute. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)

Comment: I read that guide but couldn't understand how to do that yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template use the `ng-required` directive:

```
  <select ng-required="vm.required">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
```

Because the `required` attribute is Boolean, none of the isolate scope binding will work:

```
scope: {
    //WONT work
    //required: '=?required'
},
```

Instead inject and use the `$attrs` object:

```
function BiSelectController($attrs) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.required = !!$attrs.$attr.required;
}
```

The controller uses the `$attrs` object to detect the presence or absence of the normalized `required` attribute and to set `vm.required` to either `true` or `false`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `$attrs` Type API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$attr)
- [AngularJS ng-required Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired)
- [MDN HTML Reference - `required` Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#required)